# ul image text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a custom list menu style but I am unsure how to align the text with the image:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
div#main .services{
    width:250px;
}
div#main .services ul li{
    list-style-image: url('../img/tick.png');
}
div#main .services li{
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertical alignment might help (try top or middle value):

```
div#main .services li{
    line-height:20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```